# How to use Where() with save() method?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm looking for away to use Where condition instead of `find()`, but with `save()` method

this is my code :

```
$flight = App\Flight::find(1);   // I want to use ::where([multiple conditions])

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

I tried but i'm getting an error

Comment: `I tried but i'm getting an error` what error did you get?

Comment: `Flight::find(1)` is the equivalent of `Flight::where('id', 1)->first()`. If you want a bunch of additional `where` conditions, use `::where()` instead of `::find()`; for example: `Flight::where(...)->where(...)->first()` (like suggested in the answer below). Your question is a little unclear though, as `::find()` uses an `id`, which would override other `where` conditions, and you didn't provide the actual error, so please consider [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73008152/edit) with more details. This will also help avoid downvotes in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->first()`

```php
$flight = Flight::where('active', 1)
      ->where('destination', 'San Diego')
      ->first();

$flight->name = 'New Flight Name';

$flight->save();
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-single-models